# Pass a static method to taskSpawn function as a function pointer

Tags: c++, vxworks

[taskSpawn reference](https://www.ecb.torontomu.ca/%7Ecourses/ee8205/Data-Sheets/Tornado-VxWorks/vxworks/ref/taskLib.html#taskSpawn)

```
typedef int         (*FUNCPTR) (...);     /* ptr to function returning int */
```

While sending the function pointer I get the bellow mentioned error.
I've tried all permutation combinations.

```
this->readerTaskId = taskSpawn("test1", 90, VX_FP_TASK, 20000, SerialPort::reader, (_Vx_usr_arg_t)this, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);  
this->readerTaskId = taskSpawn("test1", 90, VX_FP_TASK, 20000, &SerialPort::reader, (_Vx_usr_arg_t)this, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL); 
this->readerTaskId = taskSpawn("test1", 90, VX_FP_TASK, 20000, SerialPort::reader, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
this->readerTaskId = taskSpawn("test1", 90, VX_FP_TASK, 20000, &SerialPort::reader, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
this->readerTaskId = taskSpawn("test1", 90, VX_FP_TASK, 20000, reader, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL); 
this->readerTaskId = taskSpawn("test1", 90, VX_FP_TASK, 20000, SerialPort::task_one, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
this->readerTaskId = taskSpawn("test1", 90, VX_FP_TASK, 20000, &SerialPort::task_one, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
this->readerTaskId = taskSpawn("test1", 90, VX_FP_TASK, 20000, task_two, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
this->readerTaskId = taskSpawn("test1", 90, VX_FP_TASK, 20000, &task_two, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Error:

```
D:/Test/source/SerialPort.cpp:108:24: error: no matching function for call to 'taskSpawn'
                this->readerTaskId = taskSpawn("test1", 90, VX_FP_TASK, 20000, task_two, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                                     ^~~~~~~~~
D:/Test/../primary_source/krnl/h/public\taskLibCommon.h:277:16: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int (_Vx_usr_arg_t)' (aka 'int (long)') to 'FUNCPTR' (aka 'int (*)(...)') for 5th argument
extern TASK_ID  taskSpawn       (char * name, int priority, int options,
                ^
1 error generated.
```

Header:

```
#include <taskLib.h>
#include "vxWorks.h"

namespace TaskTest
{
    int task_two(_Vx_usr_arg_t args){return 0;} //For Testing
    class SerialPort
    {
    public:
        bool read(void);
    private:
        static int reader(_Vx_usr_arg_t args);
        TASK_ID readerTaskId;
        static int task_one(_Vx_usr_arg_t args){return 0;} //For Testing
        
    };
}
```

Source:

```
namespace TaskTest
{
    bool SerialPort::read(void)
    {
        this->readerTaskId = taskSpawn(this->taskName.c_str(), 90, VX_FP_TASK, 20000, SerialPort::reader, (_Vx_usr_arg_t)this, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);   
        //this->readerTaskId = taskSpawn(this->taskName.c_str(), 90, VX_FP_TASK, 20000, &SerialPort::reader, (_Vx_usr_arg_t)this, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);    
        //this->readerTaskId = taskSpawn(this->taskName.c_str(), 90, VX_FP_TASK, 20000, reader, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);    
        //this->readerTaskId = taskSpawn(this->taskName.c_str(), 90, VX_FP_TASK, 20000, SerialPort::reader, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        //this->readerTaskId = taskSpawn(this->taskName.c_str(), 90, VX_FP_TASK, 20000, SerialPort::task_one, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        //this->readerTaskId = taskSpawn("test1", 90, VX_FP_TASK, 20000, task_two, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if(this->readerTaskId == TASK_ID_ERROR)
        {
            printf("taskSpawn failed for Task 1\n");
        }
            
    }
    
    int SerialPort::reader(_Vx_usr_arg_t args)
    {
        SerialPort *sp = (SerialPort *) args;
        printf("Serial Port Read Started. Waiting for data...\n");
        while (true)
        {
            try //Exception is inside while statement
            {
                //Do Something
            }
            catch (const std::exception& ex)
            {
                //TODO Log Error
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reference you linked says

> The entry address entryPt is the address of the "main" routine of the
> task. The routine will be called once the C environment has been set
> up. The specified routine will be called with the ten given arguments.

Hence its signature must be the following:

```
void entry(int a1, int a2, int a3, int a4, int a5, int a6, int a7, int a8, int a9, int a10);
```

To pass that as a parameter to taskSpawn, you must cast it to FUNCPTR. Something like this:

```
this->readerTaskId = taskSpawn("test1", 90, VX_FP_TASK, 20000, FUNCPTR(entry), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved the problem using reinterprt_cast and const_cast.

```
this->readerTaskId = taskSpawn(const_cast<char *>(this->taskName.c_str()), 90, VX_FP_TASK, 20000, reinterprt_cast<FUNCPTR>(SerialPort::reader), reinterprt_cast<_Vx_usr_arg_t>(this), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: That's Undefined Behavior: the function is being called by vxWorks with **all 10**  parameters of the specified type. If it works, it's a matter of luck.

I gave you the solution as an answer [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76686799/566849).

Comment: @FabioA. Can you elaborate on this. I'm unable to understand what you are trying to convey.

Comment: The reference you quoted states that *"The specified routine will be called with the ten given arguments"*, but you are passing taskSpawn a pointer to a routine which only takes one argument. Depending on the architecture you're using and the calling convention being used, this may or may not work. For instance, if the parameters were put on stack before calling the function, but the calling convention being used stated that it's the function's duty to restore the stack before returning, then upon return the stack would not be restored because only one argument would be popped off it.